# How to reference multiple index values of an array without a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

How do I specify multiple index values of an array without iterating through all of them?

I have an array: `var boxArray = $(’.box’).toArray();`. I have 9 elements with the class `box`, so this array is comprised of the index values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

If `boxArray` index values of `[0]`, `[4]`, and `[8]` are all given a class of `clicked`, I want something to happen. I know I can use a `for` loop to iterate through the entire array, and I know I can reference just one index value (`boxArray[0]`), but how would I denote multiple out-of-order index values at once?

`$(boxArray[0, 4, 8])` doesn’t work - only the last index value is recognized. `$(boxArray[0][4][8])` doesn’t work

Is the only way to do this in JavaScript and jQuery to reference them one at a time? Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
if ($(boxArray[0, 4, 8]).hasClass(‘clicked’)) {
  // do something;
}
```

instead of

```
if ($(boxArray[0]).hasClass('clicked') &&
    $(boxArray[4]).hasClass('clicked') &&
    $(boxArray[8]).hasClass('clicked')
) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: is is possible to provide the fiddle for this ?

Comment: what's the problem with iterating over them?

Comment: I added more code up there instead of a jsfiddle. My issue with the for-loop is that I have eight total combinations of three index values which I need to reference, several of which are out of order. I'm just hoping there's a magical non for-loop way to access multiple out of order index values.

Comment: Why exactly `0`, `4` and `8`? What do they have in commun? Can they be selected by something?

Comment: Is this about TicTacToe? Because there are easier ways to check for three in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The snippet:

```js
var boxArray = $('.box').toArray();

var result = [1, 2, 4].every(function(element, index, array) {
    return boxArray[element].classList.contains('clicked');
});
console.log(result);

result = [0, 2, 4].every(function(element, index, array) {
    return boxArray[element].classList.contains('clicked');
});
console.log(result);

//

if ([0, 2, 4].every( (ele) => {return $(ele).has('.clicked');})) {
    console.log('test passed');
} else {
    console.log('test not passed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button class="box clicked">box</button>
<button class="box">box</button>
<button class="box clicked">box</button>
<button class="box">box</button>
<button class="box clicked">box</button>
<button class="box">box</button>
<button class="box">box</button>
<button class="box">box</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that do the check for you (using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object). Like this:

```
function check(arr) {
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {          // for each index (arguments after the first which is the array)
        if( ! $(arr[arguments[i]]).hasClass('clicked') ) // if one of them doesn't have the class 'clicked' then return false
            return false;
    }
    return true;                                         // if all have the class clicked then return true
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
if(check(boxArray, 0, 4, 8)) {
    // boxArray[0], boxArray[4] and boxArray[8] have the class clicked
}
// or
if(check(boxArray, 0, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7, 11)) {
    // all the .box elements at indexes 0, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7 and 11 have the class 'clicked'
}
// ...
```

**Note:** If you pass only the array as parametter (`check(boxArray)`), then the returned value will be `true`. If you want to return `false` in this case then just put this line as the first line of the function `check`:

```
if(arguments.length <= 1) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method or [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, or `every` method (like @gaetanoM's answer):

For using `map`:

```
var boxArray = []; 

$('.box').toArray().map((x, y, z) => {
  if (y === 0 || y === 4 || y === 8) boxArray.push($(x));
});

boxArray.forEach(box => {
  if (box.hasClass('clicked')) {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

For using `filter`:

```
var boxArray = $('.box').toArray().filter((x, y, z) => {
  if (y === 0 || y === 4 || y === 8) return $(x);
});

boxArray.forEach(box => {
  if (box.hasClass('clicked')) {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not the usecase of `map`. It's more of `forEach` or `filter`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I've refered the doc in the answer.

Comment: `map` is used to return an array out of the input array => so it's just a waste of ressources and should not be used just to loop an array, that's the usecase of `forEach`.

Comment: `filter` will be even clearer if you write the code like this: `var boxArray = $('.box').toArray().filter((x, y) => y === 0 || y === 4 || y === 8);`

Comment: `so it's just a waste of ressources and should not be used just to loop an array`. Can you give a document said that? MDN document doesn't mention about that.

Comment: The first line of the docs of `map` says: _The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array._ What is creating a new array but a waste of ressources!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I've NOT found any `note` that, `Don't use this method, try to use 'forEach' instead.`

Comment: Because it's clear! `map` has its usecases, `forEach` has its own ... If they're all the same then why did they bother to make  so many!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Totally, it's NOT my problem. If you want more, please contact to MDN team. I just give a tip to OP that can solve the problem.

Comment: MDN  is already providing great explanations, you just have to **read** them that's all

Answer (score 1):

you can use [jquery.fn.filter(function)](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) please.then you can check filter(..).length==[2,8].length

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var selectors=[2,8];
  
  $('.box').filter(function(index,element){
    return selectors.indexOf(index)!=-1&&$(element).has('.checked');
  }).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box{
 float:left;
 border:1px solid #000;
 width:80px;
 height:50px;
 margin:5px;
}
.active{
 color:red;
}
button{
clear:both;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>filter [2,8] without 4</button>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box checked'>.box .checked</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box checked'>.box .checked</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
<div class='box checked'>.box .checked</div>
<div class='box'>.box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to do this would be

```
if ($(boxArray[0], boxArray[4], boxArray[8]).hasClass("clicked")) {
  // do something;
}
```

Comment: In my program, your solution only seems to work on the first index value (boxArray[0]), having no effect on the next two. Maybe it's my specific code, but are you sure on the comma separation with the jQuery? I'm wanting it to make sure all of those three index values have the 'clicked' class.
Apologies - next time I'll post a fiddle for everyone.